# Do I need to glue connectors to my debug board, so they don't come off?

Tags: connector, hardware, glue

I designed a debug card for the [Virtex 7 FPGA VC707 Evaluation Kit](https://www.xilinx.com/products/boards-and-kits/ek-v7-vc707-g.html)

My card has [two large connectors Vita 57.1 (FMC-HPC)](https://www.samtec.com/standards/vita/fmc/). Each with 400 BGA pads.

I was wondering, if I shoulod use any glue to keep the connector in place.

Do you think the 400 pads are enough to hold the connectors in place? I'm connecting my debug board to the VC707, so I'm worried the connectors are going to come off of my board, when I pull my board off. I'm assembling my board by myself, so the connction might not have the best connection.

[image]

The connetor has two asymmetric pins, only not to place the connetor 180° flipped. But these provide no stability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. No glue necessary. If done correctly, the 400 solder joints provide plenty retention.

Comment: Yeah, this might be the problem. I took the exact measurements, but I have never applied solder paste and heated a connector with this size. It might get messy, right?
I untented some vias on the back side of the connector. I plan to do a continuity check, but I'm just thinking in case something goes wrong